# Python: pass multiple parameters to a function from a function in a pythonic way

Tags: python

Assume I have the following function:

```py
def func(a, b=0, c=1, d=2,...):
# Code goes here
```

I want to use it inside another function like this:

```py
def do_sth(...):
   func(...)

do_sth(...)
```

The number of parameters of `func` is big. What should I do to pass (optional) params to `func` when calling `do_sth`, because the following method is usable but not pythonic:

```py
def do_sth(a, b, c...):
   func(a=a, b=b,c=c...)

do_sth(a, b, c...)
```

Comment: I’m not seeing any dict/list, mentioned in the title, in the body of the question. How are they related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a dictionary like this (using `**` before `params` dict):

```
params = {
   'a': 1,
   'b': 2,
   'c': 3,
   'd': 4
}
func(**params)
```

To pass list, use `*`:

```
params = [1,2,3,4]
func(*params)
```